# how not to have trouble creating the same user again when testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

When i test twice the fuction to create an user i have an error that im creating the same user again. **Is there any way that i create the user just for testing and delete it automatically when the test is over with jest**? i'm using mongo with mongoose. i know i can make the function for deleting the user at the start of the test, but i know it's not a good practice[my code with the log of error that user already exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWhZM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use the beforeEach and afterEach (or beforeAll and afterAll) blocks.

https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown